# How to group by aggregation of column in foreign table with many-to-many relation in Eloquent?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am starting to get headaches over this so I thought I just post it here.
I have two tables that are related through a pivot table (as it is a many-to-many relationship). I use Laravel and Eloquent (but general help on how to achieve this with normal SQL queries is also highly appreciated).
I want to order the first table based a column of the second one but the column needs to be "aggregated" for this.

Example with Cars that are shared by many drivers and can have different colors:

```
Car-Table: [id, color]  
Driver-Table: [id, name]  
Car.Driver-Table: [car_id, driver_id]
```

I need a query that gets all drivers that **only** drive red cars and then all that **don't** drive red cars.
I have to use a query because I'll maybe do other things (like filtering) on this query afterwards and want to paginate in the end.
I already use queries that get either one of the two groups. They look like this:
In the Driver model:

```php
public function redCars() {
    return $this->cars()->where('color', 'red');
}

public function otherColoredCars() {
    return $this->cars()->where('color', '<>', 'red');
}
```

And then in somewhere in a controller:

```php
$driversWithOnlyRedCars = Driver::whereDoesntHave('otherColoredCars')->get();
$driversWithoutRedCars = Driver::whereDoesntHave('redCars')->get();
```

Is there a way to combine these two?
Maybe I am just thinking completely wrong here.

**Update** for clarification:
Basically I would need something like this (ot any other way that would lead to the same outcome)

```php
$driversWithOnlyRedCars->addTemporaryColumn('order_column', 0); // Create temporary column with value 0
$driversWithoutRedCars->addTemporaryColumn('order_column', 1);
$combinedQuery = $driversWithOnlyRedCars->combineWith($driversWithoutRedCars); // Somehow combine both queries
$orderedQuery = $combinedQuery->orderBy('order_colum');
$results = $combinedQuery->get();
```

**Update 2**
I think, I found out how to get near my goal with raw queries.
Would be something like this:

```
$a = DB::table(DB::raw("(
  SELECT id, 0 as ordering
  FROM drivers
  WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM cars
    LEFT JOIN driver_car ON car.id = driver_car.car_id
    WHERE driver.id = driver_car.driver_id
    AND cars.color = 'red'
  )
) as only_red_cars"));

$b = DB::table(DB::raw("(
  SELECT id, 1 as ordering
  FROM drivers
  WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM cars
    LEFT JOIN driver_car ON car.id = driver_car.car_id
    WHERE driver.id = driver_car.driver_id
    AND cars.color <> 'red'
  )
) as no_red_cars"));

$orderedQuery = $a->union($b)->orderBy('ordering');
```

Now the problem is that I need the models ordered like this and paginated in the end so this is not really an answer to my question. I tried to convert this back to models but I didn't succeed yet. What I tried:

```
$queriedIds = array_column($orderedQuery->get()->toArray(), 'id');
$orderedModels = Driver::orderByRaw('(FIND_IN_SET(drivers.id, "' .  implode(',', $queriedIds) . '"))');
```

But looks like `FIND_IN_SET` only allows for a column of the table as second parameter. Is there another way to get the Models in the right order out of the ordered union query?

Comment: Couple issues; `whereDoesntHave()` expects 2 params, a relationship name and additional query logic. If you don't want to pass additional logic, it would be `doesntHave()`. Second, I don't think it'll work with `otherColoredCars` as that's not exactly a relationship. You could do `whereDoesntHave('cars', function($subQuery){ ... });` and replace `...` with the logic to omit/include red cars only, etc.

Comment: Hm, no this actually works unless I made a mistake by writing down this small example. This is what I am doing in my project and I get the desired results out of it.

Comment: Do you mean a `UNION` query?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I just found out how to use unions for this and now saw your comment when I came back to add an update to my question :) Maybe you can have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `UNION` query:

```
$driversWithOnlyRedCars = Driver::select('*', DB::raw('0 as ordering'))
    ->whereDoesntHave('otherColoredCars');

$driversWithoutRedCars = Driver::select('*', DB::raw('1 as ordering'))
    ->whereDoesntHave('redCars');

$drivers = $driversWithOnlyRedCars->union($driversWithoutRedCars)
    ->orderBy('ordering')
    ->orderBy('') // TODO
    ->paginate();
```

How do you want drivers with the same `ordering` to be ordered? You should add a second `ORDER BY` clause to get a consistent order every time you execute the query.

Comment: This looks exactly like the thing I was looking for and couldn't come up with. I will try this soon and if it works I'll mark it as the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I got:

```
$driversWithOnlyRedCars = Driver::whereHas('cars',function($q){
  $q->where('color', 'red');
})->withCount('cars')->get()->where('cars_count',1);
```

Comment: I am not sure, but I might just try it (again perhaps^^).  
But if this works, why does this ensure, that drivers with only red cars are listed before everyone else?  
And I guess I couldn't then do all other possible queries afterwards? (Like sorting all drivers by name when they have the same "car status"?)

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I overread how you named the result. As far as I know, this would not get Drivers with only red cars but all Drivers, that drive at least one red car (and possibly any other one). See the first example for whereHas in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence. Additionally a query to get all Drivers with only red cars wouldn't solve my problem, as I want to have a list where all Drivers with only red cars are listed first with all other Drivers listed after them.

Comment: I appreciate the help and maybe I can use it somehow but this doesn't solve my problem. It's just another way to do something I already did in another way (getting all Drivers with only red cars). I will edit my question to make it clearer what I need.